# Can’t display diacritic characters within Cygwin terminal

Tags: windows, bash, git, cygwin

Both in Cygwin (minnty) and Git Bash I have set font to pl_PL/ISO-8859-2. It results (in both cases) in:

```
$ locale
LANG=pl_PL.ISO-8859-2
LC_CTYPE="pl_PL.ISO-8859-2"
LC_NUMERIC="pl_PL.ISO-8859-2"
LC_TIME="pl_PL.ISO-8859-2"
LC_COLLATE="pl_PL.ISO-8859-2"
LC_MONETARY="pl_PL.ISO-8859-2"
LC_MESSAGES="pl_PL.ISO-8859-2"
LC_ALL=
```

But in Cygwin, when I display Git commits’ comments - diacritical characters are not displayed properly (regardless of the font I use - e.g., Consolas, Lucida Console). The same commits’ comments are properly displayed in Git Bash. The comments have been UTF-8 encoded while saving.

I didn’t have this issue before, but once I reinstalled the OS now it occurs. Unfortunately I can’t tell what I have done differently.

Is it possible to fix that? I use Windows 7 32-bit.

Comment: what is the issue using `LANG=pl_PL.UTF-8` ?

Comment: It doesn’t show Polish diacritic characters of Git commits’ comments. But, again, only within Cygwin - the Git Bash itself displays those characters correctly, with the same ISO-8859-2 and font.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you're better off using UTF-8 and setting your locale to `pl_PL.UTF-8`.  UTF-8 is capable of supporting all languages, including Polish.  If that doesn't work, then there's a different issue which should be addressed independently.  Git by default uses UTF-8 in most cases, and so does pretty much everything else on a Unix or Cygwin system.

If you really, absolutely insist upon using ISO-8859-2, then you'll need to set the `i18n.logOutputEncoding` to `ISO-8859-2` so that it will render things in the proper character set.  Note that if you have this set in one Git configuration (the Git Bash one) and not in the other (the Cygwin one), that will explain why you're seeing different behavior.

You may also want to set your system code page to UTF-8 by using `chcp 65001` in a CMD window.

Comment: > If that doesn't work, then there's a different issue which should be addressed independently

Thank You for Your answer. With UTF-8 it also didn’t work in my case (under Windows 7):

$ locale
LANG=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

If, however, the issue does not occur in Git Bash, what would be the easiest way You could recommend to solve this? I’m rather a non-technical user, so many of those things are still new and abstract to me.

Comment: Have you set the mintty terminal settings to UTF-8 from the Options menu?

Comment: Yes, mintty; Consolas; pl_PL; UTF-8